# Singleton-Generic mixin class that holds HashMap<ClassName, List<Class objects>: Type Safety Warning

Tags: java, javafx, singleton

I'm working on a project (javaFX) where multiple `bean` classes and a `ViewModel` class for each `bean` class exist. A `ViewModel` maps each `bean` field to a `Property` field with which we work/process the data in our application. The `bean`'s data is retrieved by REST service(s) and is only available as long as they are referenced somewhere (otherwise mr. garbagecollector swallows them).

The loaded data is displayed in a TableView and depends on search criteria (= user input). If a new search is processed - independant of the search criteria - the previous TableView data empties - so the garbage collector collects all displayed data objects.

To enable data processing for multiple selected data objects (e.g. Persons) at once I want to store selected data objects into a static container to prevent them from beeing collected by the garbage collector. I've come up with singleton classes - but I don't want to create a singleton class for each ViewModel class there is.

I've read multiple posts and discussions about this and decided to implement a singleton class (`ContainerUtil`) that holds a `HashMap` of lists of ViewModel objects of any ViewModel class. The `String` name of the class is used as `Key` and the respective `List` as its `Value`.

I tried different implementations with `Class<?>` and `E` but always have a type safety error with this, which I'd like to prevent. So I've begun to re-think my solution and now I am uncertain

- if this really is good pratice?
- if I am missing something essential in my code/thinking that could prevent me from the unchecked type safety warning?
- if there might be a better approach to solve the describbed problem?

Any advice or critique with my approach is welcome!

So here's my code:

```
public class ContainerUtil
{
    private static final ContainerUtil instance;
    private final Map<String, List<?>> instances_map;


    /**
     * <p>Constructor of Class {@link ContainerUtil}</p>
     * <p>Is private to prevent other methods to instantiate this class!</p>
     */
    private ContainerUtil()
    {
        // only a single instance allowed
        this.instances_map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    static
    {
        // Instantiates the one allowed instance at application start
        instance = new ContainerUtil();
    }

    /**
     * @return The one instance of {@link ContainerUtil}
     */
    public static ContainerUtil getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * <p>Creates (if not existing in the {@link #instances_map}) and returns a list (=container) of objects of the given class<p>
     * @param containerClass - The class of which a container is needed
     */
    public <E> List<E> getContainerForClass(final Class<E> containerClass)
    {
        if (!instances_map.containsKey(containerClass.getName()))
        {
            List<E> container = new ArrayList<>();
            instances_map.put(containerClass.getName(), container);
        }
        return (List<E>) instances_map.get(containerClass.getName());
        //     ^^^^^^^^^ unchecked type safety warning
    }

}
```

**P.S.:** I'm not quite sure whether this post is more suitable for Code Review instead of Stack Overflow - if so please notify me.

Comment: Don't the container have a common superclass? Then you should be able to use `<E extends YourClass>` and `Map<String, List<? extends YourClass>>` at least.

Comment: I once had that implemented, but the warning is not resolved with it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using singleton as a "data store" sounds like a bad idea to me. It is definitely easy to make the garbage collector not to garbage collect through a singleton, but it is hard to tell garbage collector to collect it later. Of course, if you are careful about it, those data would still be garbage collected at the correct time, but you are giving yourself a chance to make silly mistakes.
2. If you insist on using the original approach, then that warning is unavoidable, you just have to suppress it.
3. I would recommend letting whichever class the `TableView` is in to keep its own list. I don't see why it is impossible to store those data without the singleton.

Comment: I don't think this will cause memory leak or s.th. alike. The containers are completely controlled by the users and their needs for it. The containers are to be used when workflows or processes has to be executed [multiple times with different data objects]. The user will have visual feedback on all current containers in use and can clear or adapt their content freely. So if the workflow(s) or process(es) to execute have finished, the user will have to clear it in its own interest (to do other workflows or processes). 
Additionally `TableView`s might be volatile.